# No module named menus.menu_pool

Tags: python, django

Installing Django-CMS and I get the following error when trying to runserver:

```
File "test/cms/models/pagemodel.py", line 27, in <module>
    from cms.menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
ImportError: No module named menus.menu_pool
```

Is there a package called menus I need to install I've tried pip install menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import it as

```
from cms.menus.menu_pool import menu_pool
```

It assumes `menus.menu_pool` is a module, which it is not.

So either change to

```
from cms.menus import menu_pool #this would import the .py file
```

Here, the usage would be `menupool.MenuPool`, and so on..

Or

```
from cms.menus.menu_pool import MenuPool #This would import the class
```

depending on how you are using it.

Alternatively (Not recommended though), you could also do:

```
from cms.menus.menu_pool import *
```